# How to select all conversation by users which also display order by last date

Tags: mysql, sql

The below query I used to get all user IDs, who message me OR message by me. It's working well. But now I want to show the last user at the top. How to do it please?

```
SELECT s.user1,s.user2 FROM(
SELECT CASE WHEN t.mfrom > t.mto THEN t.mfrom ELSE t.mto END as user1, 
CASE WHEN t.mfrom < t.mto THEN t.mfrom ELSE t.mto END as user2 
FROM messager t WHERE t.mfrom = '$ownid' OR t.mto='$ownid' ORDER BY t.date DESC) s GROUP BY s.user1,s.user2
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN t.mfrom > t.mto THEN t.mfrom ELSE t.mto END) as user1, 
       (CASE WHEN t.mfrom < t.mto THEN t.mfrom ELSE t.to END) as user2 
FROM messager m
WHERE ? IN (t.mfrom, t.mto)
GROUP BY user1, user2
ORDER BY MAX(t.date) DESC;
```

Note:

- You don't need a subquery.
- Use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with literal values.
- `IN` is simpler than `OR`.
- The solution is the `ORDER BY` with the `MAX()`.